# AssertionError: Some objects had attributes which were not restored

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, text-processing

I was training a basic LSTM on text prediction by following the official TensorFlow site [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation). I had managed to train my model up to 40 epochs on a GTX 1050ti and had saved the checkPoint file in a separate folder. However, when I now try to restore the model, I get this long error:-

```
StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function standard_gru at 0x7f9e121324d0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <function standard_gru at 0x7f9e121324d0>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function cudnn_gru at 0x7f9e120c1d40> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <function cudnn_gru at 0x7f9e120c1d40>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function standard_gru at 0x7f9e121324d0> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <function standard_gru at 0x7f9e121324d0>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function cudnn_gru at 0x7f9e120c1d40> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: converting <function cudnn_gru at 0x7f9e120c1d40>: AttributeError: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Num'
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/awesome_ruler/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py:1200: NameBasedSaverStatus.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Restoring a name-based tf.train.Saver checkpoint using the object-based restore API. This mode uses global names to match variables, and so is somewhat fragile. It also adds new restore ops to the graph each time it is called when graph building. Prefer re-encoding training checkpoints in the object-based format: run save() on the object-based saver (the same one this message is coming from) and use that checkpoint in the future.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_dir)
  File "/home/awesome_ruler/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 162, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "/home/awesome_ruler/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1398, in load_weights
    status.assert_nontrivial_match()
  File "/home/awesome_ruler/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 917, in assert_nontrivial_match
    return self.assert_consumed()
  File "/home/awesome_ruler/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 894, in assert_consumed
    (unused_attributes,))
AssertionError: Some objects had attributes which were not restored: {<tf.Variable 'embedding_1/embeddings:0' shape=(65, 256) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.00044268, -0.02351714, -0.01139065, ..., -0.00327835,
         0.00074228, -0.00383734],
       [-0.02313181,  0.04697707, -0.02350216, ...,  0.040385  ,
         0.03087702,  0.02765551],
       [ 0.0410727 ,  0.00130001,  0.0051438 , ...,  0.02899202,
         0.04258115, -0.03773504],
       ...,
       [-0.03134514,  0.01370119,  0.00993627, ..., -0.02257681,
         0.02617678,  0.03761976],
       [-0.02954974,  0.02407967,  0.02768463, ..., -0.0056519 ,
        -0.01507735,  0.04617763],
       [-0.04113789, -0.03544737,  0.01056757, ...,  0.01236727,
        -0.01791535, -0.01635399]], dtype=float32)>: ['embedding_1/embeddings'], <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 65) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-6.7811467e-02, -2.5536597e-02,  5.1763237e-02, ...,
        -6.9665730e-02,  3.9457709e-02, -5.3290475e-02],
       [ 1.5835620e-02, -3.0763537e-02, -7.4058644e-02, ...,
         3.8087368e-05, -9.1508478e-03,  5.5485427e-02],
       [ 3.8143486e-02,  8.8131428e-04, -2.3478847e-02, ...,
        -1.5135627e-02, -5.2146181e-02,  7.1185097e-02],
       ...,
       [-6.6591002e-02,  4.7627889e-02,  5.7474524e-02, ...,
         4.1528463e-02,  4.6467118e-02, -3.0670539e-02],
       [-5.0804108e-02,  5.4505378e-02, -1.5776977e-03, ...,
         2.1875933e-02, -2.9637258e-02,  2.0201296e-02],
       [-4.7325939e-02, -8.0013275e-03, -3.6348965e-02, ...,
        -7.0560835e-02, -4.9752403e-02,  1.0509960e-02]], dtype=float32)>: ['dense_1/kernel'], <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(65,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      dtype=float32)>: ['dense_1/bias'], <tf.Variable 'gru_1/kernel:0' shape=(256, 3072) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.00432818,  0.03131782,  0.00038544, ..., -0.00559966,
         0.03458985, -0.03219106],
       [-0.00865119,  0.01648769, -0.00768028, ...,  0.01366192,
        -0.03043955, -0.01382086],
       [-0.01379537,  0.00547716, -0.00385967, ..., -0.00027269,
        -0.01285852,  0.0377048 ],
       ...,
       [-0.01940641,  0.01454895,  0.03349226, ..., -0.04234404,
        -0.02699661,  0.0376601 ],
       [ 0.00186675, -0.00547577, -0.02205843, ..., -0.01287581,
        -0.02314153,  0.04158166],
       [ 0.00954719, -0.02883693, -0.03259185, ..., -0.02587803,
         0.02906795, -0.00559821]], dtype=float32)>: ['gru_1/kernel'], <tf.Variable 'gru_1/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(1024, 3072) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 9.11542401e-03,  1.50135346e-02,  2.96630897e-02, ...,
         2.25223936e-02,  2.31253020e-02, -2.96920985e-02],
       [-2.21075956e-02, -8.46013427e-06, -2.16848943e-02, ...,
        -1.26914177e-02, -3.49153839e-02, -3.01396102e-02],
       [-3.59148793e-02,  9.98445973e-03,  2.60963626e-02, ...,
         3.15430500e-02,  1.28889643e-02,  3.37569825e-02],
       ...,
       [ 3.39106433e-02,  6.54980540e-03, -1.27352085e-02, ...,
        -4.14674729e-03,  3.53236459e-02, -1.36333425e-02],
       [-3.50691415e-02, -1.76392253e-02,  1.67468414e-02, ...,
        -2.06982102e-02, -1.06042419e-02,  2.26641595e-02],
       [-1.14825107e-02, -3.46554294e-02, -1.83847174e-03, ...,
         2.25809850e-02,  2.45791934e-02, -2.70933360e-02]], dtype=float32)>: ['gru_1/recurrent_kernel'], <tf.Variable 'gru_1/bias:0' shape=(2, 3072) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>: ['gru_1/bias']}
```

I am trying to load the file `ckpt_40.index` which, as you can see is the latest checkpoint. However I am not able to. I am using this code to load my model ==>

```
checkpoint_dir = 'CheckPoints/ckpt_40.index'

model = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size=1)

model.load_weights(checkpoint_dir)

model.summary()
```

And am using the `generate_text` function from the website to predict something.

> I think a similar issue was posted [on Stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993832/load-weights-from-checkpoint-not-working-in-keras-model), but it wasn't answered. I am using Tf[GPU] 2.0- beta1 which was the latest tf version for GPU...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A really idiotic mistake I made, which was so minor that I doubt anyone could have picked it up. In this line :-

```
checkpoint_dir = 'CheckPoints/ckpt_40.index'
```

Though the file *is* named to have the '.index' prefix, For some reason attaching that extension to the variable/call function has caused it to panic for some reason(Maybe a bug). What would have been more helpful was an error to point out the incorrect extension.

So for anyone else having this problem, just change your checkpoint directory to this ===>

```
checkpoint_dir = 'CheckPoints/ckpt_40  # .index has been removed'
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer - [nothing wrong with that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: What does your directory layout look like for your saved checkpoints?

Comment: ya funny I also had the same issue error due to the path model.load_weights('/kaggle/input/lstm-transformer-cnn-approach-dataset/checkpoints/v1') this solved it then :D thx